# How to make Git Shell open newer version of PowerShell on Windows 7

Tags: git, powershell, github, command-line, windows-7

My problem is that you can see in the title of this question: I can't force Git Shell to open the newer version of PowerShell, so I get the old and ugly command line after starting Git Shell. My OS is Windows 7, downloaded and installed *GitHub for Windows* and I installed the newest version of PowerShell recently (which works perfectly when I open the actual PowerShell).

Furthermore, after starting Git Shell, but before entering the directory of any repository, the title of the CMD window says that *C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe* is running. So, maybe the real question could be: how should I make it run another, newer "PowerShell" instead (provide another path for Git Shell) and where is this located at all?

Anyone any idea, please?

Comment: if you want to have git prompt in PowerShell ISE, use [PoshGit](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git)

Comment: Already read about that, thank you. According to [this site](https://git-scm.com/book/uz/v2/Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Powershell), PoshGit should have been included in _GitHub for Windows_ in the first place. Despite this, I didn't find anything that could imply that PoshGit was installed.

Comment: It's included in the shell that is launched from GH4W, not in the global PowerShell / ISE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is (usually) only a single version of the PowerShell console installed on your computer, it is at `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe` even if it is PowerShell Vs.5

You can verify in Task Manager that both PowerShell instances are using the same binary.

If you see a different background color or a different/smaller font it's because of the console settings, which you can change in the properties of the window.

Comment: Changing colors and fonts is only one thing.
A bigger problem may be that I can't resize the window so that it fills the whole screen (the width can be only the half of the screen).

Comment: Checked what you suggested by the way: in the Task Manager, the Git Shell uses the binary found in *C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0*, while the pure PowerShell the one from *C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0*.

Furthermore, when using Git Shell, an additional *\*32* appears after the binary's name (*powershell.exe* inside Task Manager).

Comment: I forgot about the 32bit Version of PowerShell, but that's the only difference, one is 32bit the other 64bit, they should both behave the same. If you run `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` directly it should look the same. I don't have a Git Shell, so I don't know what it is doing. I'm using Git directly in PowerShell and that works fine for me.

Comment: They look the same, indeed. Launching PS (i.e., from the Start Menu) still looks different (modern, blue-background design). If you use Git directly from PS, do you have the additional Git design/extras like the Git status information at the end of the prompt (i.e., number of modified files)?

Comment: No, I don't get any git features in the prompt, I just fire up commands. Even it the Git shell starts the 32bit PowerShell, you should be able to configure it to look and behave the same way a normal PowerShell Window does. My point is, there is no old ugly version, it's all in the configuration.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to show a configuration so that the window launched by Git Shell could fill the whole screen?

Comment: sorry, I don't have or use Git Shell or GitHub for Windows.

Comment: Not a problem, only the screen size problem remains. Would anyone protest if I accepted your post because of your helpfulness and (partial) answers? :)

Comment: You can always un-accept it later when a better one comes around.

Comment: (By the way, managed to solve the size problem as well since then: had to modify the Layout settings in the Properties of the Git Shell window.)